# How can I read text file content to avariable

Tags: text

On the TIA Portal Siemens WinCC Unified engineering software there is a customised "read Text File" java script expression like HMIRuntime.FileSystem.ReadFile. But I think it is just working like fs.readFile. I have programmed the following code to read the file content inta  the variable tag1 as string.

```
let tag1;
HMIRuntime.FileSystem.ReadFile("C:\\test.txt", "utf8").then(
function(text) {
tag1.Write(text);
```

The problem is, that the content is read to tag1 but the last 3-4 characters are read additionoaly once more again.

For example: If I have the content  "The weather is fine" tag1 looks like "The weather is fine ine"
The text file I am reading from is saved as UTF8 (Notepad).
What can be the problem?. I am working the last 3 days but couldn't fix it.

Alternatevily: How can I program the same function with pure java script code?

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you add an appropriate language tag.

Comment: I did the same thing with three different texts and it works fine. Which version did you use? I used Version V16 Update 2. [![Screenshot of Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy2gq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy2gq.jpg)